# Disable Flash Audio in Browser Control .Net

Tags: .net, flash, audio, mute

Is there a way to disable Flash Audio while i'm using My Winform application which has a WebBrowser Control (gecko(firefox) and WebBrowser control IE) ?

I would block only flash audio  inside the webpage(where i navigate)  not all the sound of my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the playing of the video is all handled from within Flash, I am not aware of controlling this outside of the swf/Flash environment especially if you still want audio elsewhere.

If you have access to your swf's source .fla, you can try triggering the mute button on the flash video player. In you swf's ActionScirpt right after you load the video do something like:

```
var muteButton:MovieClip = MovieClip(myFLVPlaybackVideoPlayer.muteButton);
muteButton.on_mc.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html

Optionally you can tell flash to stop playing all sounds after loading via:

```
flash.media.SoundMixer.stopAll();
```

Even if you don't have access to the source, you can also consider simply re-encoding the video without any audio. Handbrake is free and should be able to do that if you go that route.